# Globalizing files (attachments, images) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, globalization, rails-i18n

We can use [globalize gem](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) for globalizing text fields in models. For globalizing(translating) 'designation' attribute of an employee, we use `translates :designation` in the employee model, and `employee.translations` prints the translations for the employee object (one object for each supported locale with designation in corresponding locale).

I have a model specific attribute (image for employee) which is a paperclip attachment. Need to globalize the image, so that `employee.image` will give the actual image for default locale (:en) and  `employee.image.translations` will return all the translations of the image (one image/paperclip attachment for each supported locale)

**How to globalize the paperclip attachments in rails?**

Answer (score 0):

There are a set of attributes that get added to the `Employee` model when we add a paperclip attachment `image` to it. Instead of trying to translate paperclip attachment, I added the translation of those attributes in the parent Employee model.The attributes that get added are `image_file_name, image_content_type, image_file_size and image_file_updated_at`. So, adding

```
translates :image_file_name, :image_content_type, 
           :image_file_size, :image_file_updated_at
```

and running necessary translation table migration for the employee model with these additional columns helped to globalize the paperclip attachment.

Now, employee.translations will return one object for each supported locale and each of the objects will have the `designation, image_file_name, image_content_type, image_file_size and image_file_updated_at` for the corresponding locale.